# Select with multi-column sub select query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with the following problem.

I have in total 3 tables.

1) A table with stories (posts)

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ts_story_stories                                |
---------------------------------------------------
| id | title | user_id | creation_date | category |
```

2) A table with users

```
---------------------------
| ts_user                 |
---------------------------
| id | username | ...| ...|
```

3) A table with chapter elements
(A story contains 2 < n < 20 chapters which each contains 2 < n chapter elements (like a paragraph, an image or a video))

```
---------------------------------
| ts_story2_segments            |
---------------------------------
| id | type | value_0 | value_1 |
```

I want to create a preview of a story.
A preview like this

[image: Story Preview]

I need a MySQL query that returns a set of up to 6 rows each containing
user_id, story_id, story_title, story_first_image, story_first_text

to just retrieve user_id, story_id and the story_title is fairly easy.

```
SELECT  ts_story_stories.id AS story_id, 
        ts_story_stories.title, 
        ts_story_stories.user_id AS user_id

FROM    ts_story_stories

INNER JOIN ts_user 
        ON ts_user.id = ts_story_stories.user_id  

WHERE   user_id = '{$STORY_DATA["user_id"]}' 
        AND ts_story_stories.id <> '{$STORY_DATA["story_id"]}' 

ORDER   BY RAND()
LIMIT   6;
```

The problem lies in story_first_image, story_first_text.
This is actually also quite easy.

To get the first image:

```
SELECT ts_story2_segments.type, 
       ts_story2_segments.value0, 
       ts_story2_segments.value1 

FROM   ts_story2_segments 

WHERE  (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' 
          OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') 
       AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id 

ORDER  BY ts_story2_segments.id ASC 

LIMIT  1
```

If type is 1 (image), then value0 is the image, if type is 2 (video), then value1  is the image (thumbnail).

and the first text:

```
SELECT ts_story2_segments.value0 

FROM   ts_story2_segments 

WHERE  ts_story2_segments.type = '0' 
       AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id 

ORDER  BY ts_story2_segments.id ASC 

LIMIT  1
```

I don't know how I go from these two sub queries to story_first_text / story_first_image in the main query.

Currently my full query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT  ts_story_stories.id AS _story_id, 
             ts_story_stories.title, 
             ts_story_stories.user_id AS _user_id, 
             ts_story_stories.creation_date, 
             ts_story_stories.category,     
             ts_user.username,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.type
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_type,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value0
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_value0,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value1
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_value1,


            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value0
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   ts_story2_segments.type = '0' AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS description

    FROM ts_story_stories

    INNER JOIN ts_user 
            ON ts_user.id = ts_story_stories.user_id  

    WHERE   user_id = '{$STORY_DATA["_user_id"]}' AND ts_story_stories.id <> '{$STORY}' 
    ORDER   BY RAND()
    LIMIT 6)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT  ts_story_stories.id AS _story_id, 
             ts_story_stories.title, 
             ts_story_stories.user_id AS _user_id, 
             ts_story_stories.creation_date, 
             ts_story_stories.category,     
             ts_user.username,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.type
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_type,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value0
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_value0,

            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value1
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   (ts_story2_segments.type = '1' OR ts_story2_segments.type = '2') AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS thumbnail_value1,


            (SELECT   ts_story2_segments.value0
            FROM ts_story2_segments
            WHERE   ts_story2_segments.type = '0' AND ts_story2_segments.story_id = ts_story_stories.id
            ORDER   BY  ts_story2_segments.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS description

    FROM ts_story_stories

    INNER JOIN ts_user 
            ON ts_user.id = ts_story_stories.user_id  

    WHERE   user_id <> '{$STORY_DATA["_user_id"]}'
    ORDER   BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 6)
) AS gg;
```

which is quite slow, since I have those many sub queries.
Does anyone know a better approach to solve this?

Comment: You lost me at table 3 (which is I guess where you lost yourself)

Comment: `story_first_text` isn't even a row in your database, your database row names are confusing to someone who hasn't written the code to understand. All you need to do is connect each table with a foreign key and make a WHERE clause to find it by the ID. This can be done in one query.